# How to correctly add graph in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I plot the different dataset in pandas it doesnt correctly shows the desired graph, instead it shows a linear graph which is incorrect. How should I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#cleaning the csv file
fh=pd.read_csv('Documents/ads/2019 T1_12.csv',skiprows=[0,1,3,9,15,21,27,30,31,32,33,34,35])
fh=fh.drop('Total',axis=1)
fh=fh.drop('Others', axis=1)

#plotting
plt.plot(fh['Year'],fh['Germany'])
plt.plot(fh['Year'], fh['USA'])
plt.ylabel('Number of Emigrants', fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize=17)


fh.index
fh.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `USA`'s dtype is object, causing the linear plot and the messed up ylabels.

You may need to add `thousands=','` to the `read_csv` call.

After that, see Quang Hong's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64584253/9245853) for a hint as to better visualization.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers from two countries are very different in scales `USA` in the tens of thousands, while `Germany` in the hundreds. If you look really close, you can see that the line for `Germany` is trending up by a tiny bit.

You can either use log scale on the `y` axis or use a secondary axis:

```
fh.plot(x='year', y=['USA','Germany'], secondary_y=['Germany'])
```

Comment: In OP's chart, I think blue is Germany and yellow is USA. Guessing USA is object, hence the messed up ylabels.

Comment: @Bigben Oh that's true. OP might need to read csv with `thousands=','`. You should add it as an answer. That said, my answer is still valid after that :D

Comment: The blue line graph correspond to Germany. The yellow graph belongs to USA, but it doesnt correctly shows the graph even the y axis ticks values

Comment: @KenWood I believe [BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64584307/4238408) solves your problem.

Comment: My code works perfectly just now. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @QuangHoang how convenient for you to link the answer just above yours, so it is one click instead of one scroll :)